# Is there a way to collapse rows to only show distinct names?

Tags: google-bigquery

The problem that I'm facing is I'm trying to show only the distinct names in two different columns while summing up cost.

I have tried to do MAX and Order By but none seem to match what I'm trying to create or I might be doing it completely wrong.

For example of what I'm looking for is the following:

(Data Before the Pull, does have Date associated with each row, but for the pull I'm grabbing date isn't a concern)

```
Category   |     Game     |    Sold
   FPS     | Battlefield 5|     12
   FPS     |  Division 2  |     15
   FPS     |  Black Ops   |      5
Strategy   |    TW:WH2    |     13
Strategy   |    TW:WH2    |     17
   FPS     | Battlefield 5|     15
   FPS     |  Division 2  |     10
Strategy   | Satisfactory |     12
```

What I want it to look like from the pull is:

```
Category   |     Game     |    Sold
   FPS     | Battlefield 5|     27
           |  Division 2  |     25
           |  Black Ops   |      5
Strategy   |    TW:WH2    |     30
           | Satisfactory |     12
```

Is this possible to do as I believe I've seen it before but I'm not sure how to write the code to be able to create this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

-Maykid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT category, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(game AS game, sold AS sold) ORDER BY sold DESC) sale
FROM (
  SELECT category, game, SUM(sold) sold
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY category, game
)
GROUP BY category
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'FPS' category, 'Battlefield 5' game, 12 sold UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FPS', 'Division 2', 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FPS', 'Black Ops', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Strategy', 'TW:WH2', 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Strategy', 'TW:WH2', 17 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FPS', 'Battlefield 5', 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FPS', 'Division 2', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Strategy', 'Satisfactory', 12 
)
SELECT category, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(game AS game, sold AS sold) ORDER BY sold DESC) sale
FROM (
  SELECT category, game, SUM(sold) sold
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY category, game
)
GROUP BY category
```

with result

[image]

Comment: Does it perfectly!! Thank you!!